# Facebook Graph API Non English Search Queries

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to use facebook graph api public search.
It works just fine for english search queries, for example,
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon%20&type=post

On the other hand, while setting a non english search result, I'm also receiving only english results, but non of the results in a result in the language of the search query.

For example,
[http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=ביבי&type=post](http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99&type=post)

Does not return any relevant result (the search query is "ביבי" , a word in Hebrew. None of the returned results are in Hebrew).

What could I do to fix it ?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I opned a bug regarding this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/288206177977886

Answer (score 0):

To receive response in a locale which is different from your computer default locale, you should specify it with the request. Right now there are 2 ways to do that:

1. use `&locale=he_IL` in the URL ([list of `Facebook` locales](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml)), e.g.

   https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=YOUR_QUERY&type=post&fields=message&locale=he_IL
2. use `Accept-Language` header with your request, e.g.

   `'Accept-Language': 'he_IL,he,iw;q=0.9'`

Recently, the first approach had a bug (now it works well), so I would use both of them (the first one will have more priority then another).

**Note:** Search across the specified locale will return posts available in this locale.